# Find all letters not used in a string

Tags: php, string

I want to be able to do something likes this:

```
$str="abc";
echo findNot($str); //will echo "defghijklomnopqrstuvwxyz"
$str2="happy birthday";
echo findNot($str2); //will echo "cfgjklmnoqsuvwxz"
```

Basically, it would find all letters not represented in the string and return them in an array or string.

I could do this easily with a `foreach` and arrays of characters, but I was wondering if anyone had a more elegant solution.

Comment: "happy birthday" dosen't have an "e" in it :-P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's what I came up with.

```
function findNot($str){
    return array_diff(range('a','z'), array_unique(str_split(strtolower($str))));
}
```

Comment: Just pick which one you like better.  I won't be offended if you pick another answer.

Comment: Hehe. +1 for this but anyway both answers have 4 functions that do the work ;-P

Answer (score 4):

How about this

```
$str="abc";
var_dump(findNot($str));

function findNot($string)
{
    $letters = range('a', 'z');
    $presents = array_map(function($i) { return chr($i); }, array_keys(array_filter(count_chars($string))));

    return array_diff($letters, $presents);
}
```

PS: `implode` the result if you need a string of chars, not array

PPS: not sure if it is a "more elegant" solution :-)

PPPS: another solution I could think of is

```
$str="abc";
var_dump(findNot($str));

function findNot($string)
{
    $letters = range('a', 'z');
    $presents = str_split(count_chars($string, 4));
    return array_intersect($letters, $presents);
}
```

Comment: when testing at phptester.net, I get this error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION, expecting ')' in /home/jabouzic/public_html/phptester.net/txt/c6e64dbae6ae8ca4d0cfe6639f624fb9-67.176.58.205_1.php5 on line 8`

Comment: @Ben7005: That's because anonymous functions only work in PHP 5.3+.  Not many online PHP testers support 5.3.

Comment: @Ben7005: because it uses php5.3 features. Anyway, added a shorter one, that would work with older versions

Comment: @zerkms I really liked your answer, and thank you so much for your help, rocket's was a bit more condensed, and that's what I used in my code.

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this:

```
$text = 'abcdefghijklmnop';
$search = array('a','b','c');

$result = str_replace($search, '', $text);
```

Comment: Great idea btw - to replace all chars of string in an alphabet

Comment: yes, i agree. not exactly what i'm looking for, i'd have to convert the text into n array (i know it's a built in function...)

Comment: You can use `str_split` (and `array_unique`) to convert the string to an array, and `implode('', range('a','z'))` to make the alphabet :)

Answer (score 0):

Zerk's solution is nice.  I came up with this similar example, not as elegant.

```
<?php

$alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
$alphabet = preg_split('//', $alphabet, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

$str="abc";
var_dump( findNot($str) ); //will echo "defghijklomnopqrstuvwxyz"
$str2="happy birthday";
var_dump( findNot($str2) ); //will echo "cfgjklmnoqsuvwxz"

function findNot($str)
{
    global $alphabet;

    $str   = str_replace(' ', '', $str);
    $chars = preg_split('//', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    $chars = array_unique($chars);
    sort($chars);

    $diff = array_diff($alphabet, $chars);

    return $diff;
}
```